# IAR assembler directive IF

Tags: assembly, arm, preprocessor, iar

I am starting a project on GitHub consisting of a number of ARM assembler files which should compile, in combination with on C demonstration file, with several different tool chains.

Currently the assembler files compiles with the KIEL IDE and I am trying to create a project with the IAR IDE.

I have created an IAR project and added all the assembler files (.s) and the main.c file and click on the compile file but get an error message.

The beginning of the assembler files look like this

```
IF  :DEF:__LO_ARM_TEST

GET lo_arm_test_define.s
```

but the IAR IDE gives the following error message

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYrD3.png)

[image]

Is the number of spaces before IF important etc. ?

Comment: The IAR assembler is different from the Keil assembler. Have a look at the assembler manual for IAR. In IAR you can use C style preprocessor such as #if, #define etc.

Comment: How about use `#ifdef __LO_ARM_TEST GET lo_arm_test_define.s #endif` in your .asm file?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this for a while on .s files on iar without any problem

```
#if defined(STM32F10X_CL) || defined(STM32F107)
```

Just normal .c preprocesor directives.

Best regards.